# How to check Google page rank using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, google-api

Is any way I can check the Google page rank of a web page using Objective-C without using PHP or other web scripting languages?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Google Data Objective C client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/)?

PageRank [may not](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/06/beyond-pagerank-graduating-to.html) be the metric that you should be tracking.

Comment: Which one of those APIs exposes page rank?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to google api, however I couldn't locate any PR API's.

Comment: Did you read the "Beyond Pagerank" article that I linked, which explains why you should stop depending on PR stats?

Comment: No I didn't. This is not answering on question "how". I need find the way how to check PR rank. Not the why I need to use or not to use PR rank in my project :). Thanks any way!

Comment: dg777 have you found a solution?