# google page rank in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, api, gwt

I want to find google page rank for an url. I googled out to find google rank api but i didn't find any proper solution. Can anyone guide me how to find google page rank in Objective C.

Ex: [google](http://www.google.com) For this google page rank is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

i think, it could help you!! checkout once! all the best!!

also refer this below link

[How to check Google page rank using Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840317/how-to-check-google-page-rank-using-objective-c)

Comment: i tried the above ones i didnt get proper solutions @Anilkumar

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the API. But it is paid ones. [google pageRanker](https://www.mashape.com/wherestand/google-rank-checker)